# How to join a fact table to a dimension table which has a duplicate key value while avoiding duplications in fact table?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-warehouse

How do I join a fact table to a dimension table with a duplicate key value, while at the same time avoiding duplication in the fact table that would result from the join?

Dimension table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Y8Z.png)

fact table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS7gb.png)

product look-up table (another dimension table): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGtmG.png)

I thought of using the activation date as the next unique value, but they share a month in common.

I thought of creating a snowflake schema which connects dimension table in question (marketing campaigns) to product dimension which in turn connects to the fact table with no issues.

edit:

I am designing a datawarehouse which should answer how effective marketing campaigns based on purchase data.

Purchase data which will be the core of my fact table looks like this:

product_id  timestamp sales_price user_id
1           5/9/2015   120          124
2           6/9/2015   150          129

the product lookup table looks like this:

id  product_name  model   production_cost
6    ring         2019     300
5    headband     2018     200

the marketing campaigns look up table looks like this:

startdate  enddate    type         amount_spent    currency product_id
1/1/2019   7/1/2019   print         100,000         USD      6
6/1/2019   1/1/2020   socialmedia   10,000,000      USD      6
6/1/2019   1/1/2020   socialmedia   10,000,000      USD      3

The issue is that the marketing table has duplicate product id value of 6. So, when I use it as my natural key to create a surrogate primary key for that dimension table and pull that surrogate key to the fact table as a foreign key it's going to cause duplications for anything with product_id of 6 (as it's not unique). How do I connect marketing campaigns data to fact table, whilst keeping the data integrity intact -- that is no duplications?

I thought about combining start/end date with product_id to create a composite primary key, but they share/overlap a month (6/1/2019 to 7/1/2019)

I also thought about connecting the purchases (fact table) to product lookup and then product to marketing campaigns (a snowflake schema) to avoid the duplication.

Comment: Duplicate key value? I'd expect keys to be unique.

Comment: As per question guidelines, please do not post any images. Convert it to text instead

Comment: Trying to better understand your issue: You are doing the database schema design right now and want to get the best database design, correct? To help you with this, it would be good to understand the business domain / real world objects which you want to represent in the database and on the other hand what are your expected queries. What will you ask from the database.

Comment: "join" is hopelessly vague--join exactly how & why to acheive what goal given exactly what & what's stopping you? "duplicate key value" is a contradiction in terms. So it's not clear what you are trying to ask. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS Are you using "key value" to try to refer to a column in one or both tables that you want to mention in a condition in a join? Joins are not on "keys", they are on conditions. A key is a column set that is unique in a table.

Comment: Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. (And adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear.) Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please before posting look at the formatted version of your post. Please read the edit help & advanced help re block & inline formatting for code & quotes, etc. PS Please don't tell us what the issue is or what you are going to ask, just give an introduction to a question then ask the question. Again: Please act on all the previous feedback.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: "has duplicate product id value of 6. So, when I use it as my natural key to create a surrogate primary key" Again: This does not make sense, a key cannot have duplicates. Also what does "use it as my natural key to create a surrogate primary" mean? A natural key <> a surrogate key. Try saying what you are trying to say without using the word "key". What is "connect"? (Something about querying? FKs?) Etc. Your language is very unclear. "Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean." Wander less but organize & word clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take the time to read the details of dimensional database design.

If you mean dimensional design, there is no such thing as a lookup table there; there is either a Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD), or just a Dimension. Your product lookup table could be a product lookup dimension. Your Dimension table looks imperfect, too: It does contain the element of time , but not correctly. You need - usually in this order:

- a completely arbitrary integer as a surrogate, primary, key - often populated by a sequence or defined as IDENTITY
- a business identifier - that could be the SKU for a product, first part of a business unique identifier
- the valid-from-date, second part of a business unique identifier
- the valid-to-date, '9999-12-31' for the current row, or equal to the valid-from-date of its successor
- Type 1 attributes, those that don't change over time
- Type 2 attributes, those that change over time and need a new row every time they change

There can be more columns: the Boolean current-indicator, and an inserted timestamp and an updated timestamp.

The fact table is populated from the source transactions, after the dimension table. For each transaction row, you join with the SCD table with the business identifier (SKU in our case), that must be equal and the transaction's timestamp, that must be greater or equal to the valid-from-date and less than the valid-to-date. You pick the surrogate key of the row found in the SCD to populate the fact table's foreign key.

This is an exemplary, minimal, customer SCD table, without the insert/change timestamps and without the current-indicator:

| c_key | c_id | c_from_dt | c_to_dt | c_fname | c_lname | c_loy_lvl | c_org_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 66459 | 1 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Arthur | Dent | 1 | 1 |
| 34168 | 2 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Ford | Prefect | 2 | 2 |
| 2284 | 3 | 2021-12-25 | 9999-12-31 | Zaphod | Beeblebrox | 3 | 3 |
| 84768 | 4 | 2021-12-25 | 9999-12-31 | Tricia | McMillan | 4 | 4 |
| 80080 | 5 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Gag | Halfrunt | 5 | 5 |
| 57458 | 6 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Prostetnic Vogon | Jeltz | 6 | 6 |
| 1076 | 7 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Lionel | Prosser | 1 | 0 |
| 9782 | 8 | 2021-12-25 | 9999-12-31 | Benji | Mouse | 2 | 1 |
| 42655 | 9 | 2021-12-25 | 9999-12-31 | Frankie | Mouse | 3 | 2 |
| 57348 | 10 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-10-25 | Wonko | The Sane | 1 | 3 |
| 22279 | 10 | 2021-10-25 | 2021-11-25 | Wonko | The Sane | 2 | 3 |
| 3675 | 10 | 2021-11-25 | 2021-12-25 | Wonko | The Sane | 3 | 3 |
| 95534 | 10 | 2021-12-25 | 2022-01-25 | Wonko | The Sane | 4 | 3 |
| 69529 | 10 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Wonko | The Sane | 5 | 3 |
| 34845 | 11 | 2022-01-25 | 9999-12-31 | Eccentrica | Gallumbitis | 6 | 4 |